# How to use MEAN application for mobile phone

Tags: angularjs, express, ionic-framework, apk, mean-stack

I am new in MEAN and I developed small Application in MEAN. Now I want to

use MEAN application for mobile.  can I use this application for mobile.if I am

working with ionic then .apk easily generated for mobile But If I work with

MEAN then what process I have to follow for that,can we generate .apk using MEAN

or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can't create apk bundle for using MEAN Because Angular is for only webapp. you can use ionic for hybrid mobile apps.In ionic we can use angular or react.MEAN is Mongo,Express,Angular,Node so You cant use angular for mobile Apps.With Ionic you can use angular for hybrid apps.